# SDF Python API?

Tags: python

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a plan for a basic SDF python API, similar to David's / Thomas's / LAAS's [urdf_parser_py](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf_parser_py)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/579/sdf-python-api?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There has been some discussion of python API's, and also adding xacro support, but it is currently on hold. See [gazebo issue #210](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/210).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0